# AWS AppSync - Directive "aws_subscribe" may not be used on FIELD_DEFINITION

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I'm trying to get to grips with AWS AppSync. I'm quite new to GraphQL. I've got the following GraphQL:

```
type Mutation {
    deleteParcel(geoHash: String!, type_id: String!): Parcel
    addParcel(input: ParcelInput!): Parcel
    batchAddParcels(parcels: [ParcelInput]): [Parcel]
}

type Parcel {
    geoHash: String!
    type_id: String!    
}

type ParcelConnection {
    items: [Parcel]
}

input ParcelInput {
    geoHash: String!
    type_id: String!    
}

input ParcelsInput {
    parcels: [ParcelInput]
}

type Query {
    getNearbyParcels(geoHash: String!): ParcelConnection
}

type Subscription {
    onAddParcel(geoHash: String, type_id: String): Parcel
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["addParcel"])
    onBatchAddParcels(geoHash: String): Parcel
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["batchAddParcels"])
    onDeleteParcel(geoHash: String, type_id: String): Parcel
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["deleteParcel"])
}

schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
    subscription: Subscription
}
```

All seems to be setup fine on AWS console. I get the schema.json and then run command:

`aws-appsync-codegen generate AWSGraphQL.graphql --schema schema.json --output AppsyncAPI.swift`
and get the response:

`../SnatchHQ/snatch_appsync/AppSync/AWSGraphQL.graphql: Directive "aws_subscribe" may not be used on FIELD_DEFINITION.
.../SnatchHQ/snatch_appsync/AppSync/AWSGraphQL.graphql: Directive "aws_subscribe" may not be used on FIELD_DEFINITION.
.../SnatchHQ/snatch_appsync/AppSync/AWSGraphQL.graphql: Directive "aws_subscribe" may not be used on FIELD_DEFINITION.
error: Validation of GraphQL query document failed`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file `AWSGraphQL.graphql` is your API GraphQL schema, then that explains the problem.  What you need to do is define a `*.graphql` file that defines your query, mutation, and subscription operations based on your GraphQL API.  For example, the following query definitions would match your schema

```
mutation AddParcel($geoHash: String!, $type_id: String!) {
    addParcel(input: {
        geoHash: $geoHash
        type_id: $typeId
    }) {
        ...Parcel
    }
}

query GetNearbyParcels($geoHash: String!) {
    getNearbyParcels(
        geoHash: $geoHash
    ) {
        ...ParcelConnection
    }
}

subscription OnAddParcel {
    onAddParcel {
        ...Parcel
    }
}

fragment Parcel on Parcel {
    geoHash
    type_id
}

fragment ParcelConnection on Parcel Connection {
    items {
        ...Parcel
    }
}
```

Assuming you named it something like `parcels.graphql`, you can then call the following to generate a Swift implementation of the AddParcel mutation, the GetNearbyParcels query, and the OnAddParcel subscription

```
aws-appsync-codegen generate parcels.graphql \ 
    --schema schema.json \
    --output AppSyncParcelsAPI.swift
```